# Cannot see my rewarded Ads on website using Google Ad Manager

Tags: web, ads, google-ad-manager, rewardedvideoad

I need help showing rewarded ads on my website using Google Ad Manager.

Can anyone help to understand what I am missing and why my Ad is not loading?

Here is what I'm doing and the results:

- In Delivery --> Line Items I created Line item (with a creative)
  [image]
- In Inventory --> Ad Units I Created Ad unit. The Ad unit size matches the one from the line item, 640x480. In the settings of the line item I selected this Ad unit in the inventory.
  [image]
- My understanding is that the next step would be to connect them, but my Line Item doesn't appear in my Ad Unit
  [image]
- When I create a video tag URL for the Ad unit and use it to troubleshoot my line item, I can see it in the results.
- When I create JS/HTML snippet for the same Ad unit and put it in the website, the rewarded Ad never gets loaded.

Edit:

More details of the line item setup:
[image: Size]
[image: Inventory]
[image: Creative]

Ad unit setup:
[image: Sizes]

Edit 2:
@rabsom suggested to change the Inventory type in the targeting to "Rewarded Ad" but I don't have any option like this:
[image: Inventory types]

Comment: does your line item target your ad unit ? It needs to have the 640x480v size to be able to list and select your "hint rewarded video". Could you share a test page ?

Comment: @rabsom Yes my item (now 2 of them) have the Ad unit selected in the targeting. I also tried with another size 1x1v that I saw in a rewarded Ad tutorial.
As for the test page do you mean the website where I test it? I did it locally up until now but I can publish it if it helps.

Comment: @rabsom Here is the link to the test page - https://smartle-test.web.app/ . You can set the example rewarded Ad unit from Google tutorial and it works, but mine does not.

Comment: thx for the test page. Good news : I tried with othe ad unit paths (from other networks) and your script is working fine. 

Bad news : Looks like something is wrong in you GAM UI setup. Are you sure about the adunit path ? Did you add the 1x1v size on this ad unit ? could you confirm you have a 1x1v live creative targeting this inventory ?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @rabsom. I checked the sizes and inventory config, they all match. I added more screenshots in the post.

Comment: I also had a mistake in the Ad unit ID on the test page when pressing "Set Smartle Ad unit" button. After I fixed it I still don't see the Ad but I see that the request is going out to the Ad server, however it returns 400 error code.

Comment: On you line item targeting's, try unselect the Inventory Type = "In-Stream video and audio" and select "rewarded ads"

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: @rabsom thanks for helping out so far. If this question is closed, can we continue the discussion somewhere else? I also posted it on reddit without any response so far - https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/18muird/cannot_see_my_rewarded_ads_on_website_using/

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the right inventory type.
To do so : select "rewarded ads" instead of "In-Stream video and audio" on your line item's targetings.

Comment: I don't have this option, adding a screenshot

Comment: Also I don't see such inventory type in the docs - https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/6239625?hl=en

Comment: I posted this question in webmasters, thanks for your help! https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/143974/cannot-see-my-rewarded-ads-on-website-using-google-ad-manager